# How To Display Multiple Documents From Mongodb On HTML Using Node.js & Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to display multiple documents from mongodb on my frontend html using node.js and express. it basically gets document from my mongodb and then it sends it to the ejs file and the loop executes the code, but i dont know what i am doing wrong here. please help...
here is my code snippet...

```html
var jobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Company: String,
    Job_Title: String,
    Job_Description: String,
    Payment: String,
    Phone: String,
    Email: String
})

var Job = mongoose.model('Job', jobSchema, 'Jobs')

app.post("/seejobs", function (req, res) {
    
    Job.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('main', {'docs': docs});
    });
    
});
```

and my ejs looks like...

```html
<% for (var d=0 ; d < docs.length ; d++){%>

                <h1>Company : <%= docs[d].Company %></h1>
                <h1>Job Title : <%= docs[d].Job_Title %></h1>
                <h1>Job Description : <%= docs[d].Job_Description %></h1>
                <h1>Payment : <%= docs[d].Payment %></h1>
                <h1>Phone : <%= docs[d].Phone %></h1>
                <h1>Email : <%= docs[d].Email %></h1>

            <% } %>
```

and here is the error i get...

```html
TypeError: Job.find(...).toArray is not a function
    at C:\Users\Xander CaGe\Desktop\Projects\Joby\app.js:53:16
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Xander CaGe\Desktop\Projects\Joby\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Xander CaGe\Desktop\Projects\Joby\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Xander CaGe\Desktop\Projects\Joby\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Xander CaGe\Desktop\Projects\Joby\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Xander CaGe\Desktop\Projects\Joby\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Xander CaGe\Desktop\Projects\Joby\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Xander CaGe\Desktop\Projects\Joby\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at C:\Users\Xander CaGe\Desktop\Projects\Joby\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Xander CaGe\Desktop\Projects\Joby\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\Users\Xander CaGe\Desktop\Projects\Joby\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\Xander CaGe\Desktop\Projects\Joby\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:333:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1201:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Can anyone help with my code?

Comment: `i dont know what i am doing wrong` We don't know either :) What's the output? What do you see happening? Any error? Crash? Are you getting a blank page? Anything? All we can suppose is that "something" doesn't happen as expected, but what? As far as I can tell, this code doesn't look bad

Comment: i have added the error i get.

Comment: i dont understand what i did wrong here...

Comment: Aaaah, see? With the error, somebody found right away. Now it's obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ...toArray is not a function

Regarding the error you are seeing. `toArray` is not part of the Mongoose API. Hence `Job.find().toArray` won't work. Try this :

```js
Job.find({}).exec()
.then((docs) => {
  // note 'docs' is already an Array of Documents
  res.render('main', {'docs': docs});
})
.catch((err) => {
  if(err) throw err;
});
```

See : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on @PascalLamers's answer, here's the ES6/async/await style. Add `.lean()` to get only plain JSON data instead of Mongoose objects, which is lighter and faster :

```
app.post("/seejobs", async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const docs = await Job.find({}).exec().lean();
        res.render('main', { 'docs': docs });
    } catch(err) {
        res.json(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job for you.

```
    Job.find().then(function(err, docs) {
      if(err) throw err;
      res.render('main', {'docs': docs});
    });
```